# In case of React Native upgrade failure, if I manually resolve conflicts and app builds, am I done?

Tags: react-native

I was upgrading an app from RN 0.61.5 to RN 0.62.3 and I got this final output:

```
warn Please run "git diff" to review the conflicts and resolve them
warn After resolving conflicts don't forget to run "pod install" inside "ios" directory
info You may find these resources helpful:
• Release notes: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.62.3
• Manual Upgrade Helper: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.62.3
• Git diff: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/diffs/diffs/0.61.5..0.62.3.diff
error Upgrade failed. Please see the messages above for details. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

So then I manually merged the conflicting files, run `pod install` and also `npm install`, everything is fine. The app builds and runs.

Am I just ok? It seems strange to me, it's a pretty big app I was expecting more problems. Is there anything I can check to be sure that now the upgrade is completed?

Thanks to all!

Comment: You may need to try out all the functionalities of the app and handle any deprecations manually. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-4) is one list of deprecations I found which might be relevant to you based on your react-native versions

Comment: @sushrut619 but is what I did correct? Is it generally true that in case of failure you just have to fix manually and it's just done?

Comment: Yes what you have done so far is correct. You can either consider manually fixing deprecation as a part of upgrade process or as separate bugs. Either ways you will have to address them before you can release your app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be YES. Just merge the conflicts and it's done, you'll maybe have to fix the errors found step by step.